# MVC3 .net 4.0 extensionless urls and isapi_rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, isapi-rewrite

Unfortunatly I am forced to use IIS6 for my MVC website.  .net 4.0 adds functionality to mimic the stupid hack for getting extensionless urls to work in IIS6.  My website is designed to take advantage url rewriting for SEO purposes.  The keyword urls that the client wishes to use dictate an elaborate url rewriting scheme.

The problems with Microsofts impelmentation of the feature really comes down to url rewriting and the attempt to match a pattern.  I have seen various rules that attempt to strip the dreaded eurl.axd from the url so that the patterns will match.  I attempted to use these rules

RewriteRule ^(.*)/eurl.axd/[a-f0-9]{32}(.*)$ $1$2
or
RewriteRule (.*)eurl.axd/.* $1

which does work but it also introduces other problems when there are nested redirects.  i.e. handling old urls to new ones, etc

what happens is the eurl.axd gets stripped and on the redirect the isapi_filter doesnt get the request which results in an IIS 404 errror.

Tinkering around with the urls, i came up with this possible solution.
RewriteRule ^generators/generator-parallel-capability/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$   /generators/htmlcontent/generator-parallel-capability/$1/$2 [NC,L]

it just grabs the eurl.axd portion and rewrites it to the executing url with it appended.

Is there a better way?  I have several hundred urls that meet this pattern and it would be nice to have a single rule handle them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.)/eurl.axd.$ $1 [NC]` results in some unplesant behavior when the url is rewritten more than one time.  i.e.  from an old url to the new vanity url then to the actual execution url.

Using maps, I was able to produce a pattern that works quite nicely and keeps the .htaccess file from being cluttered.

```
RewriteCond ${contentmap:$2}  >""  [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1/${contentmap:$2}/$2/$3/$4 [NC,L]
RewriteCond ${contentmap:$2}  >""  [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1/${contentmap:$2}/$2 [NC,L]
```

The first detects the pattern `/controller/some-content/eurl.axd/1234` and rewrites it to `/controller/some-controller-action/eurl.axd/1234`
the second does the same thing just without the eurl junk at the end.  this is for my dev machine running iis 7

Im sure there are better ways and I am certainly open to better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

We used one generic rule on top of the config to cut the /eurl.axd234234

RewriteRule ^(.*)/eurl.axd.*$ $1 [NC]

this must work for everything but the root.